# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in W:\home\mywork.h\www\saveuser.php on line 16

Tags: php

помогите!
не могу понять в чем ошибка(

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login'])){$login=$_POST['login']; if ($login=='') {unset($login);}}
if (isset($_POST['password'])){$password=$_POST['password']; if ($password==''){unset($password);}}
if (empty($login) or empty($password))
{
    exit("12");
}
$login=stripslashes($login);
$login=htmlspecialchars($login);
$password=stripcslashes($password);
$password=htmlspecialchars($password);
$login=trim($login);
$password=trim($password);
include("bd.php");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE login='$login'",$db);


$myrow=mysql_fetch_array($result);///<----здесь ошибка пишет.


if(empty($myrrow['id'])) {
    exit("21!");
}
$result2=mysql_query("INSET INTO user (login,password) VALUES ('$login','$password')");
if($result2=='TRUE')
{
    echo "asт</a>";
}
else {
    echo "da!";
}
?>
```

при регистрации пользователя, выдает ошибку.
бд не причем, наверно.

Comment: На данном сайте есть [поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=expects%20parameter%201%20to%20be%20resource). Им **разрешается** пользоваться

Comment: шо, опять? вы не читали ответ на предыдущий вопрос?

Comment: с тем все впорядке, все робит

Comment: ну так а в чем проблема? ошибка одна и та же.... в ответе написано как чинить. Или вы прочитали и забыли? Тогда перечитайте

Comment: я дополнил проблему

Comment: если можишь то предложите альтернативу

Comment: Альтернатива дана в первой ссылке, а также в первом же вашем вопросе, в котором подробно описано что это за ошибка и как избавиться

Comment: **1.** работает ли Ваш запрос в phpmyadmin? **2.** `if ($univer_info === false) {
    echo mysql_error();
}`

Comment: @Alex при использование вашей функции выдало You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FORM vuz' at line 1

Comment: @HardKoT Ну так замените `SELECT * FORM vuz` на `SELECT * FROM vuz`.

Comment: @HardKoT помогло?

Comment: @Alex, да! Но теперь страница пустая

Comment: @HardKoT а есть ли записи в базе? что выдает `echo mysql_num_rows($univer_info);` ?

Comment: @Alex, да в базе есть данные.

Comment: @HardKoT `"<h2>Название:$name.<br>Адрес:$city, $street.<br>Телефон: $contact.<br>Web:$web."` а должно быть `echo "<h2>Название:$name.<br>Адрес:$city, $street.<br>Телефон: $contact.<br>Web:$web."` поставьте **echo** в начале строки.

Comment: @Alex я тебя обажаю!

Comment: @Alex ты мне помог! I love You, Alex! А тут личка есть?

Comment: Не за  что) пожалуйста в след. раз не торопитесь и не поддавайтесь эмоциям. Это поможет вам не совершать таких ошибок и не делать поспешных выводов) Вам стоит удалить вопрос, т.к. он врядли будет полезен обществу.

Comment: @HardKoT не за что) пожалуйста в след. раз не торопитесь и не поддавайтесь эмоциям. Это поможет вам не совершать таких ошибок и не делать поспешных выводов. Вам стоит удалить вопрос, т.к. он врядли будет полезен обществу.

Comment: @Alex ок! так тут личка есть? я еще чучуть тебе мозг повынашу

Comment: @HardKoT на данном сайте лички нет. Если у Вас возник новый вопрос задайте его, нажав на кнопку **задать вопрос**.

Comment: @Alex, а как вопрос удалить?

Comment: @HardKoT под Вашим вопросом есть ссылки правит, удалить и т.п. нажмите на удалить. Или отправьте тревогу модераторам, указав причину "прошу удалить мой вопрос"

Answer (score -2):

Почему бы Вам просто напросто не вывести результат функции `mysql_error()` и не флудить? Там ведь написана причина ошибки, а так гадать не вижу смысла. Ошибка  произошла при выполнении запроса с помощью функции `mysql_query()`. Это ошибка могла возникнуть при: отсутствии доступа к БД, не правильно выбранная база данных, нет указанной таблицы и т.п.
Также уберите точку с запятой тут:

```
while ($univer = mysql_fetch_array($univer_info);)
```

==========
Дополнение:

У вас в запросе ошибка. Напишите вместо

```
univer_info=mysql_query("SELECT * FORM vuz");
```

**Вот это**
univer_info=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vuz");

Comment: она стоит в файле подключение к бд

Comment: @HardKoT, вот вставьте перед ошибкой функцию mysql_error() и напишите сюда ответ

Comment: через другой файл изменение идет.

Comment: бд находиться в phpmyadmin

Comment: Да вставьте вы уже то что Вас просят. PhpMyAdmin - это инструмент, а не база

Comment: пуста выдает прежднию ошибку

Comment: зачем давать ответ на вопрос-дубликат? этим вы провоцируете участника и дальше задавать вопросы такого качества. я думаю в таких случаях правильнее в комментариях дать уточнения и закрыть/удалить вопрос, а не дублировать и так уже существующие ответы.